# How to check if comments are disabled on a Youtube video, using Youtube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using [Youtube 3.0 APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert) to post comments on Youtube. When I try to post a comment on a video that have the comments disabled, I don't get any errors in the response, and there is nothing in the response that indicates so. The response's structure is:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    "channelId": string,
    "videoId": string,
    "topLevelComment": comments Resource,
    "canReply": boolean,
    "totalReplyCount": unsigned integer,
    "isPublic": boolean
  },
  "replies": {
    "comments": [
      comments Resource
    ]
  }
}
```

Nothing shows if comments are enabled/disabled.

How could I know this info?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like that is not a feature from API. You can try to get commentCount https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics.commentCount and if it =0, assume comments are disabled?

Comment: I did some work around; I got the list of comments on the video (commentThreads.list). It returns 403 error in the response when the video is not available or comments are disabled. So, I posted my comment in the callback when the response is error free. The count thing won't work because comments might be enabled but, no one posted a comment before...